# Using a String as Images Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I am working on a while loop that spits out 30 images, each image having a different name.  The way I approached this was by creating a NSString variable call img, which will be different with each iteration, i.e., "Badguy 1", "Badguy 2", ect...  Then using that string as the name of the image being created.

```
TotalShips = 1
while(TotalShips < 31){

      img = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Badguy %i",TotalShips];

      UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10,20,20,20)];

      img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Badguy.png"];
      [self.view addSubview: img];

      TotalShips = TotalShips + 1;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I haven't found very much help on changing an image's name.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: What part doesn't work?  Where are you saving these files?  Is this iPhone or macOS?

Images don't have names do they?  I think only files have names.

Comment: What doe "spits out" mean?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're trying to do... but the answer problem is that you need to be using an array or some sort of collection object.

Comment: it's also a bad idea to start variable names with an upper case.

Comment: You should not be naming your NSString and your UIImageView the same thing. In your first statement img is a string, yet on the very next line it's a UIImageView? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImageView has an property animatedImages (NSArray). Vou can easily play auround with animationDuration and animationReapCount. You can start the animation with `[myImageView startAnimation]` and stop with `[myImageView stopAnimation]`.

Please read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW3

The file names can you build in a loop with 'NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png",imageName, iterator]'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but I'll try to explain what your code does, maybe it helps you understand the problem:

```
TotalShips = 1
while(TotalShips < 31){
      // here your img variable is a string, which will be 'Badguy 1', 'Badguy 2', etc
      // you're not using this img value set here anywhere else in your code
      img = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Badguy %i",TotalShips];

      // here you redeclare your img as an UIImageView     
      UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10,20,20,20)];

      // here you assign the image in the imageView to the image 'Badguy.png'
      img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Badguy.png"];
      [self.view addSubview: img];

      TotalShips = TotalShips + 1;
}
```

So, your code creates 30 different UIImageViews , all of them with the same image: 'Badguy.png', and adds them one on top of the other to the current view. I suppose this is not what you wanted to do.